# Making a custom function for a mapped array in VueJS for a table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am working on displaying and properly sorting data in a bootstrap table in VueJS.

I am trying to replace the date format in an array from January 21, 2010 format to MM/DD/YYYY format so it can be properly sorted by a bootstrap table. The array that is coming from the API has multiple values that are joined to fill one cell in the table. In order to do this, I have been using the join function on the mapped array. For the date field, since there is only ever one value, instead of joining I wanted to create a custom function that would change the date format as stated from ex. January 21, 2010  to 01/21/2010. I was planning on just hard coding this in methods.

When I attempted to declare a function in methods I keep getting the following error:
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: item.LastUpdatePostDate.newFunction is not a function"
How would I go about fixing this? Is this a very inefficient way to change the date?

```js
computed: {
    mappedItems() {
      return this.items.map((item) => {
        return {
          Ids: item.Ids.join(""),
          Acronyms: item.Acronyms.join(", "),
          LastUpdatePostDate: item.LastUpdatePostDate.newFunction(),
        };
      });
    },
    
  },
  methods: {
    newFunction: function () {
      
      return arguments
      
    },}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value `item.LastUpdatePostDate` is a string... it has no `newFunction` method. The `newFunction` method is available via `this.newFunction`, and you should pass the date string as argument:

```
LastUpdatePostDate: this.newFunction(item.LastUpdatePostDate),
```

`newFunction` itself could look like this:

```
newFunction: function (dateString) {
    let [monthName, day, year] = dateString.match(/\w+/g);
    let month = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec".indexOf(monthName.slice(0, 3)) / 3 + 1;
    return `${day}/${month}/${year}`.replace(/\b\d\b/g, "0$&");
}
```

But maybe give it a more telling name ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a vue method on a value.

Call the method with the value as argument:

```js
...
    LastUpdatePostDate: this.newFunction(item.LastUpdatePostDate),
...
newFunction(date) {
    // do stuff with date
    return newvalue
}
....
```